# Django's only() still selects every existing field

Tags: django

I have a Django model consisting of multiple fields. I only wish to select one.

I use only() as, according to the documentation it should return only the `woodAsked` field here. Yet the returned queryset will still contain each and every field in the `Painting` model.

```
 >>> a = Painting.objects.only('woodAsked')
 >>> serializers.serialize("json",a)[1:200]
'{"model": "binaryQuestionApp.painting", "pk": 3, "fields": {"name": "Getty00052501.jpg", "objectNumber": "00052501.jpg", "collection": "Getty", "title": "pretty after al", "woodAsked": 0, "woodYes": '
```

How can I select ONLY the 'woodAsked' field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for [`values`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.values) or [`values_list`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#values-list)

```
 a = Painting.objects.values('woodAsked')
 a = Painting.objects.values_list('woodAsked', flat=True)
```

Only *defers* the other fields, making it so that they aren't returned on the initial query - but still exist

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for. I don't understand only() it seems. in `a = Painting.objects.only('woodAsked')`, doesn't `a` represent the initial query? I would think only the `woodAsked` fields would be in there.

Comment: @MitchellvanZuylen - imagine a more complicated model where you may have array fields that could possibly take longer to return the values. You don't really have a need for those values so there isn't any point in fetching them in your query. `only` allows you to avoid the extra fetching time

Comment: @MitchellvanZuylen `.only()` still returns model instances, but replaces the fields that aren't loaded with descriptors that will fetch the field from the database on first access. It's an advanced function that's only useful for very specific performance tweaking. You don't need it. (Unless you have extensively profiled your application and concluded that you _do_ need it.)

Comment: @knbk Thank you for the explanation, not it makes sense. I wrongfully though it would simply only return that field, not fetching the others, at all.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `values` or `values_list`,

*OR*

If you only want a subset of fields to be serialized, you can specify a fields argument to the serializer,

```
data = serializers.serialize('json', a, fields=('woodAsked'))
```